# PHP parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"."' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ';'

Tags: php, syntax, tostring

```
class Animal{
public $name;
public $color;
public function __construct($name,$color){

      $this -> name=$name;
      $this -> color=$color;
      }
      public function intro(){
      echo "<br> The animal is {$this -> name} and the color is {$this -> color}.";
      }
        public function __toString() { //89th line
            return "Name of the object is " .$this ->name ".";
      }

}
```

I cant run my code because of the "PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"."' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ';' in /home/yKJgGf/prog.php on line 89". But i think this code is not false. I cant find the solution how to fix this error.

Comment: There is a dot missing to concatenate.

Comment: Missing concatenation here: `" .$this ->name ".";` Between name and the double quote

Comment: `i think this code is not false`...think again, then. The compiler doesn't randomly lie to you. Work with the reality, not how you wish it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
class Animal{
public $name;
public $color;
public function \__construct($name,$color){

      $this -> name=$name;
      $this -> color=$color;
      }
      public function intro(){
      echo "<br> The animal is {$this -> name} and the color is {$this -> color}.";
      }
        public function __toString() { //89th line
            return "Name of the object is " . $this ->name . ".";
      }

}
```

Missing a dot after `$this->name` to append the remaining string.